# Woocommerce, Order Meta with Email

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I can't figure out with this problem: when woocommerce sends the order processing mail to custumer, customer's meta properties are valorized in the $order object, and the valorization is done by the execution of the action woocommerce_email_order_meta (at least, I suppose):

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text );
```

All fine with that, but when I want to create a custom template for that email, no meta values will be displayed in the result, although the same invokation.

I've checked the parameter values passed to the "woocommerce_email_order_meta" invokation (that routes to the order_meta() function in plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php) of my costum template, and those values are the same.

Neither debugging the order_meta() function in both cases gave me clues, the function's behavior is always the same, but the result in the mail is different. So... what can I do for insert order meta info in this mail?

Sorry if this question is a duplicate and for my bad english.

Thanks in advance if you can help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you post the function you are hooking to woocommerce_email_order_meta?

Comment: Is the order_meta() in plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php, you can find it here: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Emails.html#274-312 but as I sayed, the function's behavior it's the same even when using the default template

Comment: Why you want to create a new template? why you can't modify the current template

Comment: @AndresMauricioCastillo
The function is order_meta contained in [link](plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php) . In both cases has the same behavior, but dunno why the mail result is different. Thx for taking care of it :)
[edit]The comment is posted twice 'cos I had connection trouble and the first one was not notified as sent[/edit]

Comment: @AndresMauricioCastillo I swear, connection here is awful, sorry for anachronistic answers... Yes I want to create a new mail template, but I can't reach the order meta, I followed the same steps of the original template but on despite of what I aspected, no property such billing_address or billing_firstname can be reached with this costum template... EDIT: It's the only thing that doesn't work in the new template, everything else that is not an order meta such as total or items is perfectly visible

Comment: can you post the custom email template code?

Comment: That info billing_Adress, billing_firstname, etc its not added by this hook its added by other template part with this code: wc_get_template( 'emails/email-addresses.php', array( 'order' => $order ) );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Billing address and other details, such as first name and last name are stored as order details (In "postmeta" table). Whereas, Products in the order, its quantity, price is stored as Order meta.

Therefore, "woocommerce_email_order_meta" action will display order meta details.

Please make sure, you have included the below line, in your custom email template to get Billing address and other details.

```
<?php wc_get_template( 'emails/email-addresses.php', array( 'order' => $order ) ); ?>
```

For more information regarding, Email template customization, you can refer our blog ,

http://wisdmlabs.com/blog/customize-woocommerce-order-emails/

Comment: Hmmm, I need an holydays: I haven't seen it from the original template, unbelievable! You're my daily hero, thanks a lot :) really appreciate your help!

Comment: So, if I have a custom field in an order called custom_tracking_number, how do I display that in the Order Complete email?

`get_post_meta( $order->id, "custom_tracking_number", true )` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Garconis, You can do something like this: 

add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'include_my_order_custom_fields');

 function include_my_order_custom_fields( $keys ) {
   $keys[] = 'custom_tracking_number';
   return $keys;
  }